# ARSCNView freezes when presenting and dismissing UIViewController over it

Tags: ios, arkit

I have setup a AR project. All seems to be working but I am not able to keep the AR session going when I present and dismiss a view controller over it.

So, I have a AR session setup like Xcode's sample project shows. Pretty simple. I then do this when the user taps on a button on the screen:

```
let myVC = MyVC()
present(myVC, animated: true) {

}
```

MyCV comes on screen and then I select an option, then the screen is dismissed:

```
dismiss(animated: true) {  }
```

After MyVC is dismissed the ARSession looks frozen on in the view controller.

So, I thought maybe I have to tell it to run again so I added this line in the completion:

```
dismiss(animated: true) { 
    self.sceneView.session.run(ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration())
}
```

Nothing.

then I check on the delegate calls to make sure I wasn't getting any error:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    // Present an error message to the user

}

func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
    // Inform the user that the session has been interrupted, for example, by presenting an overlay

}

func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
    // Reset tracking and/or remove existing anchors if consistent tracking is required

}
```

None of those is ever called during that process.

Why does the AR session appear frozen when precasting and dismissing a simple ViewController over it?

Comment: What presentation style are you using for `MyVC`? See [ARKit Session Paused and Not Resuming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44979559/957768).

Comment: @rickster I did not modify it, the default, UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen

Comment: @rickster I just tried "UIModalPresentationStyle.popover" and same logic does not freeze the AR... so, it's working now with popover... so, this means I can't use a fullSCreen?

Comment: As noted in the linked Q&A, you shouldn't *want* to present another VC fullscreen if you expect the user to come back to the same AR experience afterward, because the only "safe" thing you can do upon coming back from a period without tracking is lose all the AR content.

Comment: Yup, makes sense. I was thinking about this the wrong way. Thx.