# Camera freezes when I come back to viewcontroller containing ARSCNView

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, arkit

I am working on ARKit where I save a video during an ARSession. I present another view controller where I can watch my video. When I come back to my first view controller, the camera seems to be frozen although session delegates are called. I cannot add nodes either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put ARSCNView in Tabview controller without freezing the ARSession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056160/how-to-put-arscnview-in-tabview-controller-without-freezing-the-arsession)

Comment: Using popover presentation solved my problem.  [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979559/arkit-session-paused-and-not-resuming