# ARKit Resuming Session

Tags: ios

I have an ARKit app which allows the user to add a cube to the scene. This works fine and I can see the cube. But when I push the app to the background and then move the device to another location (by walking to a different room) then ARKit session is unable to determine the correct position of my old nodes.

Is there anyway I can find a workaround this problem so that when the app is resumed from coming to foreground from the background then it still remembers the position of the nodes.

UPDATE: I am looking into saving the lat and long for the user and then somehow converting those lat and long to SCNVector3 to put the node.

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't be able to keep the AR running in the background. Apple does not recommend pausing the session or interrupting it and trying to resume:

> **Avoid interrupting the AR experience.** If the user transitions to another fullscreen UI in your app, the AR view might not be an expected state when coming back.
>
> Use the popover presentation (even on iPhone) for auxiliary view controllers to keep the user in the AR experience while adjusting settings or making a modal selection. In this example, the `SettingsViewController` and `VirtualObjectSelectionViewController` classes use popover presentation.

The issue is that once the session gets interrupted, the device stops using it's mechanisms that keep track of AR Nodes as well as your location, might have to set up a mechanism that keeps the app running constantly in the background and running the ARSession through that. You might be able to find projects on github that allow for running in the background. Another issue you might face is Apple's limitations with running apps in the background, [which is apparently 3 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275415/how-long-does-apple-permit-a-background-task-to-run).

If you're at all interested in restarting the AR Session one you came back in, you can see [my answer on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979559/arkit-session-paused-and-not-resuming/45609051#45609051).